# Convert String to time format and append with current date - Shell/ksh

Tags: shell-script, date

I am looking to take a string as command parameter like `HHMMSS` and convert it to time format like `HH:MM:SS` and append it to current date (date needs to be generated within the script using 'date' command )

For example, if my command line argument will be `093500`, this should be converted to `09:35:00` and be appended with current date like,
`2018-05-16 09:35:00`

Example:

```
$ ./convertTime.sh 093500
2018-05-16 09:35:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. Works as so:

```
$ ./format_date.sh 092533
2018-05-17 09:25:33
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

format_time(){
    point=0
    while [ "$point" -le "${#1}" ];
    do
        string=$string"${1:$point:2}"
        if [ "$point" -lt "$((${#1}-2))"  ]
        then
        string=$string":"
        fi
        point=$((point+2))
    done
    echo "$string"
}

echo "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" "$( format_time "$1" )"
```

This takes advantage of parameter substitution, typical of `bash` and `ksh`, so this suits your question tags, but it is not suitable for POSIX `/bin/sh` since `${variable:position:offset}` form doesn't work in POSIX `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 4):

If by `ksh`, you mean ksh93:

```
$ t=093500
$ DATEMSK=/dev/stdin <<<%H%M%S printf "%(%F %T)T\n" "$t"
2018-05-17 09:35:00
```

Or:

```
$ printf '%(%F)T %.8s\n' now "${t//??/\0:}"
2018-05-17 09:35:00
```

Or portably (shells of Bourne or csh families or `fish`)

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d $t" | sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)$/:\1:\2/'
2018-05-17 09:35:00
```

(for rc-like shells, use `date +'%Y-%m-%d '$t` instead)